# How do I merge 2 Excel files into one excel file with separated sheets?

Tags: c#, excel

I've 2 Excel files, and I want to merge them into 1 file with separate sheets..

I trying to perform the merging with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, 
but I don't understand how to use that?

> for Yahia:

here the methods for get a Range that i want to merge them with different file:

```
internal object[,] GetValues(string filename)
    {
        object[,] values = new object[0, 0];
        try
        {
            Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            values = ExcelScanIntenal(workBook);

            workBook.Close(false, filename, null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return values;
    }

    private object[,] ExcelScanIntenal(Workbook workBookIn)
    {
        object[,] valueArray = new object[0, 0];
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workBookIn.Sheets[1];

        Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
        valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
        return valueArray;
    }
```

and here i want to merge the values:

```
   internal void AddWorksheetToExcelWorkbook(string filename, string worksheetName, object[,] valueArray)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
        Sheets xlSheets = null;
        Worksheet xlNewSheet = null;

        try
        {
            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
                return;

            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets as Sheets;

            xlNewSheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlNewSheet.Name = worksheetName;

            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlNewSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            xlApp = null;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that xlNewSheet isn't have any property that can to get the values.. how can i to add??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the question is... but for merging excel files programmatically see for a starting point:

- http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/242869-How-merge-two-excel-sheets-c.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

IF you need more information then show some code please and tell what exactly isn't working...

EDIT - as per comment:

You can use `xlNewSheet.Cells` to get a Range and use its `Columns`/`Rows`/`Item` properties change/add any values you want - i.e. in your case from `valueArray`...

Comment: here i get the Range that i want to merge to another file:

Comment: i tried to us xlNewSheet.Cells.Insert or xlNewSheet.Cells.set_Item or xlNewSheet.Cells.set_Value but always get errors.. can u explain more? thanks..

Comment: when i using "xlNewSheet.Cells.set_Value(valueArray, Type.Missing);" i get Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

Comment: ohh, now i understand:  for (int row = 1; row < valueArray.GetLength(0)/2 + 1; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col < valueArray.GetLength(1)/2 + 1; col++)
                        {
                            object o = valueArray[row, col];
                            xlNewSheet.Cells.set_Item(row, col, valueArray[row, col]);
                        }
                    }