# DevExpress export GridView to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, devexpress

I really need help with this.. I can't find any example on the internet
I am using DevExpress GridView I need to send it to excel and I'm getting problems to loop to every cell and column because DevExpress contains different methods then the DataGridView

that's the code that i'm trying to write.. I really Appreciate your help

```
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

    string FirstName = "First Name";
    string FatherName = "Father Name";
    string LastName = "Last Name";
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\Emp.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"";

            con.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema;
            dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand ("select * FROM [" + dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    private void ExportBtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < gridView3.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            //ExcelApp.Cells[1, i] = gridView3.Columns[i].HeaderStyleName;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i< gridView3.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = gridView3.Columns[j].ToString();
            }
        }
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\Users\\pc\\Emp.xlsx");
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        ExcelApp.Quit();
    }
```

My problem is in the Export button the click event.. There's no such thing as Row()

Comment: You can use [DevEx export mechanism](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument995).

Comment: I'll try it but i wish if i could knew where's my fault..
Anw Thank You..

Comment: The DevExpress grid doesn't offer an internal collection of row objects like the DataGridView, so you cannot just say row[3].column[2]. Instead you would use the [GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads) method in your loop to retrieve the value of a certain cell.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To know various export methods of XtraGrid, go through [Export Methods and Settings](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument995)

Use [GridControl.ExportToXls(String)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ExportToXlstopic833) Method

Example code snippet:

```
private void mnuExportTable_ItemClick_1(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel (2003)(.xls)|*.xls|Excel (2010) (.xlsx)|*.xlsx |RichText File (.rtf)|*.rtf |Pdf File (.pdf)|*.pdf |Html File (.html)|*.html";
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            string exportFilePath = saveDialog.FileName;
            string fileExtenstion = new FileInfo(exportFilePath).Extension;
            
            switch (fileExtenstion)
            {
                case ".xls":
                    gridControl.ExportToXls(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    gridControl.ExportToXlsx(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                case ".rtf":
                    gridControl.ExportToRtf(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    gridControl.ExportToPdf(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                case ".html":
                    gridControl.ExportToHtml(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                case ".mht":
                    gridControl.ExportToMht(exportFilePath);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (File.Exists(exportFilePath))
            {
               try
               {
                   //Try to open the file and let windows decide how to open it.
                   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exportFilePath);
                }
                catch
                {
                    String msg = "The file could not be opened." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Path: " + exportFilePath;
                    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
             }
             else
             {
                 String msg = "The file could not be saved." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Path: " + exportFilePath;
                 MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
[Exporting Several XtraGrid Controls to a Single Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318573/exporting-several-xtragrid-controls-to-a-single-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

try below code. SaveFileDialog1 is tool
also add required references --

```
 Try

        Dim sv As New SaveFileDialog1
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK And SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> Nothing Then
            If SaveFileDialog1.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") Then
                Dim path = SaveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
                GridControlAFP.ExportToXlsx(path)
                Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
                Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet")
                xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:XFD1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()

                xlWorkBook.Save()
                xlWorkBook.Close()
                xlApp.Quit()
            End If


            MessageBox.Show("Data Exported to :" + vbCrLf + SaveFileDialog1.FileName, "Business Intelligence Portal", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            SaveFileDialog1.FileName = Nothing

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The `selectgridvalues` function returns the values in the Database in Datatable format.
Calling this function in the show button sets these values in the gridcontrol. 
Export button exports the values into an Excel sheet in .xlsx format

```
    //function to get values from DataTable to gridControl Devexpress
    public DataTable selectgridvalues()
    {
      SqlConnection con;
      con = new SqlConnection();
      con.ConnectionString = "server='SERVER';uid='sa';pwd='1234';database='DBName'";
      con.Open();

      SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tablename order by id ", con);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      adp.Fill(dt);
      gridControl1.DataSource =dt;
    }


    //code on showdatagridview values button
    public void buttonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        gridControl1.DataSource = selectgridvalues();
    }


     //code on export to excel button
     private void buttonExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogExcel = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialogExcel.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        if (saveFileDialogExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string exportFilePath = saveFileDialogExcel.FileName;
            gridControl1.DataSource = selectgridvalues();
            gridControl1.ExportToXlsx(exportFilePath);
        }

    }
```