# empty row and column while Exporting Several XtraGrid Controls to a Single Excel File

Tags: devexpress

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318573/exporting-several-xtragrid-controls-to-a-single-excel-file) and tested, it works but my problem is that there are one wide empty column (column A) and one wide empty row (row 1) in every sheet (in excel file). I know that this is the setting of PrintingBase class. But how can i remove those first empty column and row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer to my own question:

```
var compositeLink = new CompositeLinkBase();
var link1 = new PrintableComponentLinkBase();
// this is the margins in sheet1
link1.Margins.Left = 0;
link1.MinMargins.Left = 0;
link1.Component = DG1;
compositeLink.Links.Add(link1);
// then export to excel :)
```