# devexpress multiple gridview export to excel in Single File winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, export-to-excel, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

Searched and found the following solution 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318573/exporting-several-xtragrid-controls-to-a-single-excel-file)
Users have given up vote to it but it throwing an exception for me.

> MultiFileExportToExcel Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' to type 'DevExpress.XtraPrinting.IPrintable'. 
>   Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView' to type 'DevExpress.XtraPrinting.IPrintable'.

Full code is here:

```
 Public Sub MultiFileExportToExcel()
    Using saveDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel (.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim printingSystem = New PrintingSystemBase()
            Dim compositeLink = New CompositeLinkBase()
            compositeLink.PrintingSystemBase = printingSystem

            Dim link1 = New PrintableComponentLinkBase()
            link1.Component = CType(GridView1, IPrintable)
            Dim link2 = New PrintableComponentLinkBase()
            link2.Component = CType(GridView2, IPrintable)

            compositeLink.Links.Add(link1)
            compositeLink.Links.Add(link2)
            Dim options = New XlsxExportOptions()

            options.ExportMode = XlsxExportMode.SingleFilePageByPage
            compositeLink.CreatePageForEachLink()
            compositeLink.ExportToXlsx(saveDialog.FileName, options)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Thank in advance..

Comment: `CType(GridView1, IPrintable)` is the error im guessing. Looking at the solution I think you should just use `GridView1`. This is the solution code; `link1.Component = grid1;` as you can see there is no casting.

Comment: Got same error.

Comment: Just to be sure, you changed the code for both `link1.Component = GridView1` _and_ `link2.Component = GridView2`?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/acp3ce8rzk2w42t/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I can't click on that link. I'm seeing slight differences in the solution code to yours. For example are you definitely using a `GridControl` rather than a `GridView`? Maybe that's causing an issue?

Comment: that's it. Thank you it worked. I wasted my 2 to 3 hours to find out a solution for it. that shows, I am new to coding :)

Comment: Is there any way to give name to each worksheet that exported using above code? Like I exported excel file (named myReport.xlsx) that have 10 sheets called sheet1, sheet2 sheet3 and  so on.

Comment: I would look at creating a new question @JagjeetSingh. It's the way things work here at SO.